# Tracking Y axis end value and apply some logic

Tags: javascript, processing.js

I was playing with processing js on khan academy. I have stucked on a point to apply my logic to make the drops start back at the top once they've reached the bottom, using a conditional. I just need to track the `Y axis` endpoint and call my `setXYPositions()` to apply re rain ability.

```
var xPositions = [];
var yPositions = [];

var setXYPositions = function(){

   for(var i = 0 ; i <= 400 ; i+=10 ){
    xPositions.push(i);
    yPositions.push(random(1,100));
   }
};

//call rain
setXYPositions();   

draw = function() {

    background(204, 247, 255);

    for (var i = 0; i < xPositions.length; i++) {
        noStroke();
        fill(random(2,255), random(2,255), random(2,255));
        ellipse(xPositions[i], yPositions[i], 10, 10);
        yPositions[i] += 5;

    }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you know when a `yPosition` index has reached the bottom of the sketch area? What value does it have when that happens?

To find this out, try using just a single `yPosition` instead of 40 of them. Print out the `yPosition`, and figure out what it is when it goes off the bottom of the screen.

Thinking about it another way: it looks like you're using the default size of `100x100`, meaning the height of your window is 100 pixels. If the `yPosition` of the top of the window is `0`, what is the `yPosition` of the bottom of the window?

Hopefully that helped you figure out that the bottom `yPosition` of the window is `100`. Now that you know what, what do you want to do when a circle reaches that? You want it to reset to the top of the window, right? Well, what's the `yPosition` of the top of the window? We already said that it was zero!

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
yPositions[i] += 5;
if(yPositions[i] > 100){
   yPositions[i] = 0;
}
```

What happens if you change the size of the window (by calling the `size()` function from `setup()`)? We'd have to change the `100` in that `if` statement. But Processing actually makes our lives easier by giving us a `height` variable that we can use instead!

```
yPositions[i] += 5;
if(yPositions[i] > height){
   yPositions[i] = 0;
}
```

Now our code will work no matter what size the window is.

Shameless self-promotion: I've written a tutorial covering animation and resetting positions available [here](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/animation).

Comment: it works :) and I liked your self-promotion because it helps me understand animation :)